# One way replication with CouchDB

Tags: database, couchdb, database-replication

I run CouchDB on my production server, and I want to periodically replicate it to my development server (running on another machine, at my home). So what's the easiest way to do it securely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Replication can occur over HTTPS, at least not yet. (I believe that feature is coming with v1.1)

If you need it to be secure (ie. encrypted over the wire) you should probably use ssh/scp to periodically copy your database files to your development server.

Comment: I've used `stunnel` for things like this. It's pretty easy to set up. You can also set up an SSH tunnel: `ssh -L 5984:localhost:5984 username@remote-host-address`. Once that is up, `localhost:5984` will go through SSH and hit the remote server on port 5984.